What are the shortcomings in Kant's description of the process of human cognition?
According to Kant, sensory data is first received by our body. This produces stage no. 1: sensation. So, at this stage, we are only aware that sense data has arrived.
Then, after our body processes this sensory data further, we are able to perceive what that sensory data is pointing toward. Kant says this is stage no. 2: we have just made an intuitive representation.
After that, the brain applies our mind's internal concepts to this intuition, and then we are able to understand what that sensory data is pointing toward. This is stage no. 3: conceptual understanding.
And thus, the entire process of cognition is summarized in three steps. Is my caricature of Kant correct?
My question is, after more than 200 years of neuroscience research since Kant's first Critique, is this still exactly how modern scientists believe that cognition happens? For starters, are the three stages really so separated out and sequential? What is the correct SOTA picture today? I hope this is the correct SE.site to have asked this question.

Your description has very little to do with Kant. There is no "sensory data", there is only "undifferentiated manifold of sensation" that contains no data. The "data" only appears after it is framed by forms of intuition and schematized. And it is not "pointing toward", the things in themselves are unknowable, all we get are appearances formed with our own active participation. A physical model of perception is not what Kant was interested in. On relation to modern theories see Brook, Kant and Cognitive Science.

I'm not sure if it's relevant to your question, but this process is missing the feedback effects that go into sensing. Expectations are sent to the sense organs, which biases their perceptions. And conditioning can cause some sensations to be ignored completely.

Your caricature of Kant's account of cognition is a fairly accurate simplification. Today neuroscientists do not separate intuition as cleanly from conception, research shows that even early in the sensation or perceptual process, higher-level brain areas which are responsible for conception can attend, interact and influence dynamically simultaneously...

@DoubleKnot That, ie. that intuition and understanding cannot be untangled as neatly as he tried conceptually to identify different necessary conditions of the possibility of cognition, is what Kant writes himself at the end of the deduction, though. The third critique goes in the same direction more deeply.

@PhilipKlöcking Kant later in the third critique delves into their fluid interplay mainly for the aesthetic judgment and intention, yet modern neuroscience covers all types of judgment including the non-aesthetic common ones. By the way, are you concluding Kant’s evolved self-hedging makes his description without shortcoming as exactly opposed to OPs' titular question?…


According to current neuroscience a stimulus (physical, chemical,
etc.) reaches our sense organs. It transforms into a signal in the
form of an electrical neuronal excitation pattern. The signal is
send to the corresponding sensory field in the brain, passing one or
more stages of filtering and integration with other signals.
In the
sensory fields of the cerebrum the arriving signals are split and
analysed according to several different algorithms. The results are
integrated and further distributed to the sensory areas in the
cortex, where they are matched and assessed by the stored memory
content.

Kant’s description of information processing in the brain from the
viewpoint of the first person is not completely off the mark. But it lacks of course
all the current neuroscientific explanations from the third person
view obtained by the different techniques of functional brain imaging.
And it is questionable which algorithms in the
neuronal nets of the brain correlate with the two principal "algorithms" of Kant’s
epistemology: Intuition and categories.


Nevertheless Kant made an important point which is still valid: Our mind constructs experience, experience is not just imaging.

+1 Our mind constructs experience — Yes. And it constructs space and time themselves
